# MS Visio Import external Data from API or MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, flask, odbc, visio

Disclaimer: My Usecase might not be possible to implement

I want to import external data from MongoDB to MS Visio and it is not possible to install an ODBC Driver on all the clients. I am using Flask as Backend and the most convenient way would be to provide an API which delivers the Data from mongoDB as a csv file by accessing something like http://127.0.0.1/csv/Customername.

None of the provided Dataimport methods in Visio seem to support accessing a WebAPI:
[image]
On the Backend i either get some sharepoint requests (/_vti_bin/webs.asmx HTTP/1.1) or some Webdav requests ("PROPFIND /csv HTTP/1.1" 404)

Is there any way of either providing a CSV from an API or Access MongoDB with a Proxy on the backend that translates to a relational database format supported by Visio?

-I Tried importing an Excel file and entered the url as source address
-Creating a ODBC Datasource with Microsoft Text Driver and the url as source address
-Using a predefined ODBC DSN for Excel Files

I delivered the CSV/XLSX File as download and as readable text in the HTML and expected Visio to either download or read the data:
[image: HTML Output]
[image: Download]